# How to add another IF statement in Excel and If A1=2 Then round output otherwise dont round?

Tags: excel

I Have a formula that am trying to embed another If statement in.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A10),"0",ROUND(A17+B1+B10+((A17+B10)*B1)+((I1+B10)*B10),0))
```

I need to embed another If that if A2=1 Then Round else don't round.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is like this, albeit it's kind of ugly.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A10),0,IF(A2=1,ROUND(A17+B1+B10+((A17+B10)*B1)+((I1+B10)*B10),0),A17+B1+B10+((A17+B10)*B1)+((I1+B10)*B10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel only recognises 15 significant places so rounding to 15 decimal places is really equivalent to not rounding at all, hence you can simply use your existing formula with a simple IF on the 2nd argument of round, i.e.

`=IF(ISBLANK(A10),"0",ROUND(A17+B1+B10+((A17+B10)*B1)+((I1+B10)*B10),IF(A2=1,0,15)))`

Comment: ugh.... you know, I knew my answer was easier and that I didn't have to write the formula twice... at the moment, I couldn't see where to stick the extra `IF`. @John - This is answer is cleaner :)